# How can I implement YouTube Resumable Uploads for myself without Oauth

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am looking at the documentation on [Resumable Uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol), and I noticed that I need to use OAuth for creating an application for other people.

However, I would like to use this protocol for myself, and see what I can do with it. Is there any demo Oauth that I can do, or another way to authenticate (but for my personal self?)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Comment: The API does not have such dicriminants: you (quote: *my personal self*) and others. *OAuth is required by the very specification of the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#auth) API endpoint.* There's no way to avoid it!

Comment: I personally would not recommend you to implement resumable video uploading from scratch. That's quite tricky to done it right. It's more feasible to start from a fully working example (e.g. for Python [`upload_video.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py)), and modify it such that to fit your needs. Google's API client libraries for a plethora of programming environments/languages are also open source (e.g. [that for Python](http://github.com/google/google-api-python-client)).

Comment: So the solution is to use a library, submit the code to OAuth Verification Request, and hope it works?

I would like to write this in the browser :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For browser-side scripting, there's Google’s Client Library for Browser-side JavaScript, [`GAPI`](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client). See the official document [Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/js) for the initial steps you have to be going through.

Then look into the *resumable upload* implementation provided by Google:

- [`upload_video.js`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/upload_video.js), and
- [`cors_upload.js`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/cors_upload.js).

Once again, your app has to implement one one way or another an OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flow, if you'll not make use of `GAPI`. (See [this doc](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/auth.md#oauth-20-basics) too.)

The official document w.r.t. the kind of authentication/authorization required by your app is: [OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow).

Comment: These examples are a mess, they mix concerns, have poor naming conventions, and its really hard to follow whats happening where, are there any other examples? did anyone else get this working?